# Oracle Cross join

Tags: sql, oracle, cross-join

I've got these three tables.

Table1:

```
Resource1
Resource2
Resource3
```

Table2:

```
Period1
Period2
Period3
```

Table3:

```
Resource1 Period1
Resource1 Period2
Resource1 Period2
Resource2 Period1
Resource2 Period1
Resource3 Period3
```

I need to get this result:

```
Resource1 Period1
Resource1 Period2
Resource1 Period2
Resource1 Period3
Resource2 Period1
Resource2 Period1
Resource2 Period2
Resource2 Period3
Resource3 Period3
Resource3 Period1
Resource3 Period2
```

I tried outer joins but no effect. I have found that probably cross join should help but I was not successfull in implementing it. Could be someone so kind and help me with this stuff?

Thank you very much,
r.

Comment: Could you explain rules how to create your result set? What do you mean by "unneccessary rows"?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusion. I will delete note about unneccessary rows from description, right now. 
Rules are:
Table1 contains all resources.
Table2 contains all open periods in the system.
Table3 contains resources who made something in particular period. (duplicates are possible)
Every resource needs to have all open periods mentioned with his name AND if he already has in Table3 mentiond open period no matter how many times, these data must be there too. 
So result: duplicates from Table3 should be there and when some of open periods from Table2 are missing, they should be there too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a common table expression to generate all the combinations, then use an outer join to include the duplicates shown in `table3`.

```
with cte as ( select resource, period
              from table1 cross join table2 )
select cte.resource
       , cte.period
from cte
     left outer join table3
          on (table3.resource = cte.resource
             and table3.period = cte.period ) 
;
```

---

This may not produce the right answer, depending on what you mean by " I don't know how to get rid of unneccessary rows ".  The output you present doesn't appear to discard *any* rows from the tables and you haven't provided any rules.  So, if this doesn't give you what you want you must edit your question to clarify matters.

Comment: You don't necessarily need a CTE but I think this answers catches the wanted result.

Comment: @ypercube - I agree the WITH clause is not mandatory but I like them because they can help clarify a query's structure.

Comment: It works exactly I needed! Now I can see why my solutions were all bad. I was always missing this second condition: and table3.period = cte.period
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I get your result,but I am not sure whether my thought is right or not..

```
SELECT A.RESOURCEID,B.PERIOD 
FROM 
TABLE1 A CROSS JOIN TABLE2 B
UNION ALL
SELECT RESOURCEID,PERIOD
FROM TABLE3 C
GROUP BY RESOURCEID,PERIOD
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36667/2

Comment: that sqlfiddle.com is great, thak you for sharing this

Comment: @roxor year,it's really convenient,I also found it from others here : )   .